# lp_solve ignoring trivial restrictions

Tags: linear-programming, lpsolve

I made a really simple linear problem for `lp_solve`.

```
$ cat test.txt 
max: 100X ;

X <= 0 ;

bin X ;
```

The right answer shall be that X has to be 0, as it is a binary variable and cannot be 1 due the restriction. However the result is:

```
$ lp_solve test.txt 

Value of objective function: 100.00000000

Actual values of the variables:
X                               1
```

What explains this behaviour? I am doing something wrong? This also happens when alike restrictions are present on larger problems.

Comment: I think LpSolve is unhappy when all constraints are removed. Of course this is a bug: the solver should be able to return a valid solution also in the case when all constraints are presolved away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when `lp_solve` does its preprocessing, it is eliminating your constraint altogether. Then the fact that `X` is binary kicks in and the Objective function is shown to be 100. (Incorrectly)

You can see that this is happening by running with the `-stats` flag:

```
./lp_solve -stat test.lp
Constraints: 0
Variables  : 1
Integers   : 1
Semi-cont  : 0
SOS        : 0
Non-zeros  : 0  density=nan%
```

The zero constraints and nan% density could be causing this unexpected behavior.

There a couple of workarounds for this.

1. If you eliminate the `X bin;` constraint altogether, it will solve it correctly and give you an objective value of 0.
2. Another 'hack-like' fix is to add a dummy variable to your trivial constraint. Now the entire constraint gets recorded by lp_solve.

For example, try to change your `test.lp` to be:

```
max: 100X ;

X  + x_dummy <= 0 ; 

bin X ;
```

Which now gives the proper:

```
Constraints: 1
Variables  : 2
Integers   : 1
Semi-cont  : 0
SOS        : 0
Non-zeros  : 2  density=100.000000%
```

Hope that helps.